# Closing a fragment that is inflated inside the FrameLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

In my code, I have a button on OnClick of which I inflate a FrameLayout with a fragment by starting a Fragment Transaction. Now the fragment is inflated into the frame layout.

But I have a button inside the fragment view on click of which i want to close that fragment and show the activity where the button clicked open the fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while opening your fragment in Activty

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.framelayout, yourFragment, "your_frag")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

```
btnInFragment.setOnClickListener(v -> getActivity().onBackPressed());
```

Override your onBackPressed method of Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
       getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   }
   else {
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

Comment: This actually closes my main activity as well.

Comment: Can there be something like finishing a fragment

Comment: I updated the code with this solution. It still closes the main activity.

Comment: @ManmohanGupta I updated onBackPressed() method check that.

Comment: Thanks man...! found the error. It works like a charm. just saved my day.